# How can I find IPA charts that pairs each language's phonemes, with a common word feat. that phoneme in that language?

Tags: ipa

How can I find equivalents to the following chart (for American English), but for the world's currently most spoken e-languages?

E.g., the chart for Modern German must SCHEMATICALLY map out each of its phonemes, and each phoneme must be tailgated by a common Modern German word featuring  that phoneme. Vowels MUST be charted in a triangle or quadrilateral. Useless to list out phonemes unordered or unschematic!

[image]

These two pages stem from the 2013 10 edn. of Fromkin, Rodman's *An Introduction to Language*. My library doesn't have the [2018 11 edn](https://www.cengage.com/c/an-introduction-to-language-11e-fromkin/9781337559577PF).

Comment: There is no correspondence between Russian phonemes and the IPA characters.

Comment: @Anixx How so? I don't speak Russian.

Comment: Because IPA was designed for English.

Comment: Well, IPA was designed for alphabetic languages with Latin characters, yes. Plus the folk-linguistic way Cyrillic handles palatalized consonants is not coherent with IPA principles. But it's still an alphabet and I would bet that Russian readers could cope with IPA transcriptions better than English readers. Check to see if your library has any back issues of _Le Maitre Phonetique_, which was published entirely in IPA (for English and French) for decades.

Comment: @jlawler it is not folk-linguistic, have heard about phonetic analysis? It is taught in all Russian schools. There is nothing folk-linguistic about it. As to Latin alphabet, IPA lacks characters for many phonemes that have separate letters in other Latin-based but non-English languages, such as German z, Polish c, Italian c, etc.

Comment: @Anixx This is nonsense and a distraction. Italian "c" is roughly the same as English "ch", which, sure, is two characters, but *is listed* in the table above, together with its IPA counterpart, /tʃ/. The IPA is also much more straightforward to read for an Italian speaker than an English speaker, as many of its most common characters in those languages are based on Latin, not English, sound mappings. At any rate, whether or not the IPA characters actually match the language's own characters, and whether it takes just one or a digraph, has no bearing on the ability to make tables like above.

Comment: @LjL "together with its IPA counterpart, /tʃ/" - no. This is not a counterpart. The IPA counterpart is /t͡ʃ/, 3 characters. And in many languages /tʃ/ and /t͡ʃ/, /ts/ and /t͡s/ are different phonemes.

Comment: @Anixx *in that table*, that's exactly the stated counterpart.

Comment: @LjL this means the table is wrong.

Comment: @Anixx Pretty much everything you’ve said about the IPA here has been utterly incorrect. The IPA was not designed for English. The Romic alphabet was designed for English, and the original phonetic alphabets made by the Phonetic Teachers’ Association were primarily designed for English, French and German; but by the time the association became the International Phonetics Association and the alphabet the International Phonetic Alphabet, it was designed to be language-agnostic. And yes, there are absolutely correspondences between Russian phonemes and IPA.

Comment: @Anixx As for the tables in the question, they do not use /tʃ/, but /ʧ/, one character. According to the _Handbook of the IPA_, the tie bar is optional for representing affricates (“joined by a tie bar **if necessary**”) and is only used in examples in the book to disambiguate where the language makes a distinction, which German and English (the languages represented in the tables) do not. The single-character ligatures have been superseded in official IPA usage, but notably the canonical computer coding tables specifies that their supersessors _do not_ include the tie bar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "which German and English (the languages represented in the tables) do not" - that's why I say, IPA was not designed for languages iother than English and uses different characters to represent the same sounds in different languages. What needs 1 letter in Russian, needs 3 characters in IPA. And whether something is "necessary" is decided subjectively, so IPA is ambiguous even more than English spelling.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet by the way, I think, German makes a distinction in this case, I just do not know it enough to bring up a good minimal pair. Something like Platzfuehrer vs Platsfuehrer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet eh, and the German speakers finally suggested me an example of a minimal pair: Schuttsauge vs. Schutzauge. Thus, IPA is not well suitable for German either.

Comment: @Anixx Yes, IPA allows for variation when representing different languages, in order to minimise the amount of diacritics needed. That doesn’t mean it was designed for English – it uses as many multi-character entities for English as for any other language. There’s no reason a phonetic alphabet should have exactly one character for every possible phoneme in any language. _Schuttsauge_ isn’t actually a word as far as I can tell (what is a ‘rubbish eye’?), but if formed, it would be homophonous with _Schutzauge_. If you had _schuttsaugen_ (to vacuum up rubbish) and _Schutzaugen_, those would ->

Comment: -> be a minimal pair between /ts/ and /t.z/, but that’s a different thing. (_Schuttsaugen_ isn’t really a word either, but it at least makes more sense as a coinage than the rubbish/debris eye.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Journal of the IPA publishes articles ("Illustrations") exemplifying the use of the IPA in various languages, which has some of the properties that you seem to desire. You will have to decide which languages that they illustrate are most-spoken e-languages.

Comment: And all of those illustrations are gathered together in _The Handbook of the International Phonetic Association: A Guide to the Use of the International Phonetic Alphabet_ available at the IPA official website together with free audio files: https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/content/ipa-handbook-downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by yourself: make you desired schematic diagram using following links and vowel charts, just split them up - like in your example:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Standard_German
[image: German Vowels]
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Spanish
[image: Spanish Vowels]
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/French
[image: French Vowels]
; etc.

But their phonology somewhat complicated, so I will not to do just like in your example.

Comment: I'm befuddled. First you wrote "You can do it by yourself". But in your last sentence, you wrote "But their phonology somewhat complicated". Didn't you contradict yourself? I've never studied linguistics in university.

Comment: @ugro I mean that your desire isn't useful to learn phonology of this languages. Just for an excursion to. But it easy to do even for never studied person, because you can take words from given links and put them into the charts.